# How to use html to connect mysql workbench data？

Tags: html, database, web, mysql-workbench, connector

I am doing a user web interface for a database system using html. However I have no idea about how to access and manipulate the database in mysql workbench. Any code that i need to use for connect them？

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you need a server based language, so something like PHP or Node would connect your frontend to your database.

Answer (score 0):

You will need Azure or AWS or something of the sort. You will also probably need some sort of framework like Spring.

http://spring.io
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/?v=17.44